# Robotic automation application - Error related to using Selenium With Chrome In Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have developed a Java 17 and Maven 3.9.2-based robotic automation application that automates Chrome through Selenium. to perform report download tasks. This operation works fine when performed locally, But I am facing a docker issue related to selenium dependencies when building a docker image.

**These are the steps followed**

Using this command the application can be executed in local development environments. All dependencies are retrieved via Pom.xml.(Listed Below)

**mvn clean install -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties**

But When attempting to build this docker imager using the below command I get this set of errors. (Indicated Below)

**docker build --build-arg MAVEN_OPTS="-DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties" -t selenium-app .**

What causes this error? Should any changes be made to the Docker file to handle selenium-based dependencies? I use JDK 17 and Maven 3.9.2 for local building and it works fine. Could this be a limitation of the base image and how should it be updated in the Docker file?

**E.g.** # Use the official Maven image as a build stage
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17 AS builder

**Docker file used**

```
# Use the official Maven image as a build stage
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17 AS builder
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the source code to the working directory
COPY . .
# Build the Maven project and create the JAR file
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties"
RUN mvn clean install $MAVEN_OPTS
# Use the official OpenJDK 17 image as the final image
FROM openjdk:17
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the JAR file from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/report-automation.jar /app/report-automation.jar
# Copy the appropriate config file based on Maven profile
COPY src/main/resources/config-dev.properties /app/src/main/resources/config-dev.properties
# Copy the Configuration.xlsm file from the source to the working directory in the container
COPY src/main/resources/Configuration.xlsm /app/src/main/resources/Configuration.xlsm
# Expose the port (if your application listens on a specific port)
# EXPOSE 8080
# Set the entry point for the container (replace with your main class)
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "report-automation.jar"]
```

**Errors encountered.**

```
#0 850.1 FAILED CONFIGURATION: u/BeforeClass openBrowser
#0 850.1 org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --headless], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: src/main/resources/report/}}}, error Command failed with code: 65, executed: [/tmp/selenium-manager1364351565415906507905426336786135/selenium-manager, --browser, chrome, --output, json]
#0 850.1 request or response body error: operation timed out
#0 850.1 Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
#0 850.1 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-150-generic', java.version: '17.0.2'
#0 850.1 Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:25)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:13)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:99)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:72)
#0 850.1 at Infra.BasePage.openBrowser(BasePage.java:121)
#0 850.1 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
#0 850.1 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
#0 850.1 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
#0 850.1 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
#0 850.1 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
#0 850.1 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:308)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:71)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
#0 850.1 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
#0 850.1 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Command failed with code: 65, executed: [/tmp/selenium-manager1364351565415906507905426336786135/selenium-manager, --browser, chrome, --output, json]
#0 850.1 request or response body error: operation timed out
#0 850.1 Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
#0 850.1 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-150-generic', java.version: '17.0.2'
#0 850.1 Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager.runCommand(SeleniumManager.java:151)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager.getDriverPath(SeleniumManager.java:273)
#0 850.1 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:22)
#0 850.1 ... 36 more
#0 850.1
#0 850.1 SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass closeBrowser
#0 850.1 SKIPPED: DownloadReportCSV("Comprehensive Sales Report Detailed", "Enable")
#0 850.1 Download Reports CSV
```

**pom.xml**

```
   <!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>report-automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- Default config file for fallback -->
        <config.file>config.properties</config.file>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version> <!-- Use your specific version -->
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Model.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>Configuration.xlsm</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <!-- Profile for Development Environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <config.file>config-dev.properties</config.file>
                <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Profile for Local QA Environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>localqa</id>
            <properties>
                <config.file>config-localqa.properties</config.file>
                <activeProfile>localqa</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Add profiles for other environments -->
        <!--
        <profile>
        <id>clientuat</id>
        <properties>
        <config.file>config-clientuat.properties</config.file>
        <activeProfile>clientuat</activeProfile>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
        <id>clientqa</id>
        <properties>
        <config.file>config-clientqa.properties</config.file>
        <activeProfile>clientqa</activeProfile>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
        <config.file>config-production.properties</config.file>
        <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        -->
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ExtentReports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OpenCSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- maven-invoker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update 1: Changing deprecated OpenJDK image**

As a replacement for the base image mentioned in the above docker files the below-mentioned ones should offer an alternative.

hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.9.3-amazoncorretto-17/… (Correto for Java 17) and hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.9.3-eclipse-temurin-17/… (Temurin Java 17) both replacements for hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.4-openjdk-17/images/.

Updated to a maven:3.9.3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine but the issue persists. So need to look at other possible options.

Comment: What exactly is your question? JDK 17 as base? I would reconsider that because in the meantime we have JDK 21 available.... Also why using an old Maven version base image? Better use Maven 3.9.6 + JDK as base image (https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/tags?page=1&name=3.9.6-) also why do you have maven-invoker as dependency? Also the plugins are bit out of date (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ?

Comment: The main issue is the error related to Selenium With Chrome In Docker. To fix this the base image was updated 3.9.3-eclipse-temurin-17. This Project is based on Java 17 and Maven 3.9.2 so I am compelled to use the version compatible with it. I will check on the Maven dependencies and update them as suggested.